# Error webform phone field

Tags: webforms

I have a webform with phone field. I am using this modules:

- Webform Bootstrap Layout (webform_bt_layout)
- Webform Captcha (webform_captcha)
- Webform Country List (webform_country_list)
- Webform
- Phone Number (webform_phone)
- Webform Validation (webform_validation)
- CCK Phone Converter (phone_cck_convert)
- Phone (phone) Phone Country
- Locator (phone_country_locator)
- Phone Number (cck_phone)
- Webform Phone Number (webform_phone)

When I try submit form appears the next error:

"Fatal error: Call to undefined function valid_phone_number() in /Users/carlosfranco/Sites/as/sites/all/modules/webform_phone/webform_phone.components.inc on line 237"

I go to the file in the line 237 from webform_phone.components.inc and the code is:

```
function webform_validate_phone($element, $form_state) {
  $value = $element['#value'];
  if (isset( $value ) && $value != '') {
    $ccode = $element['#webform_component']['extra']['country'];
    //run through 'phone' module's validation
    if (!valid_phone_number($ccode, $value)) {
      $country = phone_country_info($ccode);
      form_error($element, t($country['error'], array( '%value' => $value )));
    }
  }
}
```

Really, I can´t see what is the problem. I am new in php and not found the error

Could anyone help me to resolve this problem please?